# Como atribuir target=”_blank” a todos os links externos após o ajax terminar de carregar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Olá, tenho um blog no wordpress onde preciso que todos os links externos sejam abertos em uma nova guia ao clicar. Porém esses links são carregados pelo ajax e a função que tenho é executada antes do ajax terminar de carregar tudo.

```
$(function() {
$("a[href^='http']:not([href*='zaha.in'])").each(function() {
   $(this).click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    }).addClass('externalLink');
});
});
```

Então tentei através do javascript definir um intervalo de tempo para dar tempo deexecutar a função jquery após o ajax terminar, no entanto também não funciona:

```
  // Instanciar a função
   niceJavascriptRoutine = null;

    // Inicio do jquery
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Função jquery
        function niceJqueryRoutine() {
            $(function() {
               $("a[href^='http']:not([href*='zaha.in'])").each(function() {
                   $(this).click(function(event) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                         event.stopPropagation();
                         window.open(this.href, '_blank');
                    }).addClass('externalLink');
               });
            });
        }
        // Passa a função jquery para a javascript
        niceJavascriptRoutine = niceJqueryRoutine;

    });
    window.setInterval(niceJavascriptRoutine,  22000);
```

Alguém saberia alguma maneira de realizar isso após o ajax carregar por completo? Detalhe que não posso editar os arquivos da requisição ajax por serem parte de um plugin do wordpress, então precisaria que isso ocorresse por fora.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar adicionar o atributo `target` nos links:

```
$("body, document").on("click", "a[href^='http']:not([href*='zaha.in'])", function(e){
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Desse modo ele funcionara em todos os elementos dinâmicos que serão gerados pelo ajax apos o carregamento da página, porque está adicionado um evento no "body, document"

Comment: não funcionou, ainda assim após o ajax ser carregado ele não atribui o target

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver não precisa atribuir eventos de click aos links `<a>`, basta apenas inserir o atributo `target="_blank"` que já irá abrir em uma nova guia.

Como você não sabe quanto tempo o Ajax irá levar para processar, uma forma é criar um setInterval que ficará rodando até encontrar um link externo definido no seu seletor. Assim que o `if` no setInterval for atendido, significa que o Ajax foi processado e os links foram inseridos, então basta adicionar o atributo `target` a todos os links de uma só vez, sem a necessidade de laço `.each`.

Veja como fica:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var niceJavascriptRoutine = setInterval(function(){

      var as = $("a[href^='http']:not([href*='zaha.in'])");

      if(as.length){
         as.attr('target', '_blank')
         .addClass('externalLink');
         clearInterval(niceJavascriptRoutine);
      }
   }, 1000);

});
```

O setInterval vai ficar rodando a cada segundo, e quando houver algum elemento na página que foi definido na variável `as`, irá aplicar o `target` a todos os elementos e parar o setInterval.

Agora, o ideal mesmo era buscar os links dentro de algum contêiner aonde o Ajax os inseriu, caso contrário o seletor `a[href^='http']` irá buscar na página toda, e se houver algum link externo que não foi inserido pelo Ajax, o setInterval irá parar logo no início.

Deveria ser algo assim:

```
var as = $("#div a[href^='http']:not([href*='zaha.in'])");
            ↑↑↑↑
   especificar a div alvo do Ajax
```